# Why was Fairy Tail disbanded?

Tags: fairy-tail

Why suddenly the guild members decided they go each on his way?

As Lucy describeds it, no one opposed the decision of just close the guild.

Comment: do yu mean when they left to train?

Comment: @Dragon Near the end of the anime and before the current arc in the manga Natsu and Happy decided to go on a training journey.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your question can be answered only in big spoiler as it is revealed in the next chapters. So...

### SPOILER ALERT

> Makarov disbanded Fairy Tail so that its members would not get caught in a fight with the Alvarez Empire. After he disbanded the guild, he went to the Alvarez Empire where it was revealed that the Emperor is none other than Zeref himself. Zeref wanted the Lumen Histoire, which is Mavis' body (or more precisely, her ability to use imagination) in order to fight Acnologia. Lumen Histoire is hidden in the basement of Fairy Tail guild building. If the guild is not disbanded, then the whole members would get killed in the fight due to the sheer difference in power between them. At least this was what Makarov thought.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason why Makarov disbanded Fairy Tail is because of Lumen Histoire. It is one of the strongest spell of Fairy Tail including Fairy Sphere and Fairy Glitter. It is still a mystery what Lumen Histoire is hence, the reason why fairy tail got disbanded.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know (by the anime) Makarov just disbanded the guild for an unknown reason. Nobody really knows for sure why he did. Maybe many of the guild members just didn't want to argue, or maybe it's because maybe they all thought that it would be best to go their separate ways.

Comment: Didn't he disband the guild so they wouldn't be caught up in the fight?

Comment: How do you mean ?

Comment: It's explained in the answer above, beware for spoilers if you've only seen the anime.

Answer (score 0):

Based off the anime I think the guild was disbanded because Makorov wasn't able to be the master any more and the only person qualified that would do it was none other than Natsu and because he left Mokorov had no choice but to disowns the guild.

Answer (score 0):

I think Macarov disbanded the guild because he knew zeref was coming and he wanted to avoid being in a fight with him and keep fairy tail safe

Answer (score 0):

I think Makarov disbanded the guild because there was probably danger ahead of them and Makarov wanted to protect them, but couldn't bare to tell them that there was more danger after their battle with the Underworld king. Makarov probably wanted to protect them and solve the problem by himself without harming people from the guild.

Comment: Can you add sources to this?

Answer (score 0):

In chapter 439 of *Fairy Tail*, it's revealed that the disbanding of Fairy Tail was because of Lumen Histoire.

There's a country (let's just say country A) that has tried to take Lumen Histoire for themselves before by invading the country, but they got stopped by the council at that time. Now, however, (when Fairy Tail was disbanded) the council didn't exist anymore and Fairy Tail and its country needed time to rebuild everything so that country A had gotten the opportunity to do what they couldn't before and Makarov knew that. He also knew that Fairy Tail wasn't strong enough to be their opponent yet, which was why he disbanded the guild and went to that country to stall sometimes.